# Values not inserting into database table android

Tags: android, database

I'm using SQLAssetHelper 
(using this import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper)

This is my code:

```
    public void storetrans(String eng, String chav, int lang){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if(lang==0){
        values.put("engchav",lang);
        values.put("chaveng",0);
        values.put("eng",eng);
        values.put("chav",chav);
        database.insert("prevtrans",null,values);
        Log.e(TAG, "check");
    }else{
        values.put("engchav",0);
        values.put("chaveng",lang);
        values.put("eng",eng);
        values.put("chav",chav);
        database.insert("prevtrans",null,values);
        Log.e(TAG, "check");
    }

}
```

This appears in my Android Monitor

```
01-02 21:45:11.665 14563-14563/exodia.e2c E/DatabaseAccess: check
```

but when I check my database file it does not change. My table(prevtrans) is still empty.
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Your debugging is weak. It always says "check", in both cases. How do you distinguish between them?

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: Rotwang I changed them both now. They work but my table is still empty.
yotamhadas No. My application runs fine but the table is empty.

Comment: Try this: `int i = database.insert("prevtrans",null,values);` followed by `Log.e(TAG, "Inserted rows: " + i);`

Comment: typecasted it and it says
01-02 22:21:57.394 1437-1437/exodia.e2c E/DatabaseAccess: Inserted rows: 1

Comment: well its meaning its added succesfully, there is probably some other code that deletes it.

Comment: Is this the reason why it isn't inserting in the table?
01-02 22:23:04.667 1437-1445/exodia.e2c W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/exodia.e2c/databases/WordBank.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Then, you have your culprit. A non closed transaction (meaning that it will rollback ALL your changes). You are probably opening a transaction (which I find unnecessary, for a single INSERT) and you aren't managing it.